# Rhyming book about a girl named Carrie who drove a car

Tags: identification-request

I can't remember the title of this book from my childhood.

It was about a girl called Carrie who drove a car. It rhymed. It was from 1980s or before. It went "Carrie's car goes near and far, she's such a keen driver you know." Her car rattled but it was sweets making the noise!

It's driven me mad for years—pun intended!